# Ruby On Rails - Where would I look for the source function for render :partial => 'x' in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I am modifying a Ruby Rails application - Redmine. I want to modify a function that renders a partial preview. In the view I believe this is accomplished via

```
<%= render :partial => 'documents/form' %>
```

I need to modify the function this is attached to.

Where might I look for this? 
Is `render` the function I am looking for? 
Is `:partial` a parameter? What does the `=>` operator do?

*I do realize learning Ruby and Rails would solve these issues, but for the current situation I just need to know enough to make a small tweak. I know it's not in the controller.*

Comment: Why do you want to modify `render`, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you would like to change the code for the partial itself, and just want to know where to find the template for that partial, not change the `render` method, which is part of Rails itself, as some of the other answers have suggested.

The `render` method tells Rails to render a particular template, possibly with some parameters passed in. A partial is a kind of template that is intended to render only a fragment of a page, such as an individual widget or a single section of the page. The syntax `render :partial => "documents/form"` is Ruby's way of passing keyword arguments to method; it is essentially just saying to render `documents/form` as a partial template. (In Ruby, this is actually equivalent to `render({:partial => "documents/form"})`, which is just invoking method `render`, passing in a hash table in which `:partial`, a keyword, maps to `"documents/form"`, a string).

So, the code that will actually be rendered is the partial `documents/forms`. By convention, partials are loaded from files prefixed with `_`; and if you're using the default ERb template format, then they will likely end in `.html.erb`. As all view code is stored in `app/views`, you will probably be looking for `app/view/documents/_form.html.erb`. Yes, this is a not particularly obvious bit of convention, but that's Rails for you.

See the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) on partials and rendering for more information.

Comment: This is the most sane answer... I do hope Josh actually meant "edit the template" rather than "modify a function" as he wrote.

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for. The application involved WYSIWYG editor CKeditor in Redmine, but for some of the "partial" descriptions of a couple pages in Redmine were rendering full HTML so text using h1, h2, etc. was getting rendered ridiculously large in the descriptions below titles. I ended up editing the view to strip HTML tags for the display on the pages involved. Your assumptions were correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `render` method in `ActionController::Base` class. It takes hash of options as parameter.  (BTW, if you can't recognize ruby hash when you see one, maybe it's a bit early for you to "tweak" rails. You can always go through some Ruby tutorial first)

As you know, monkeypatching is very, very bad, blah-blah-blah, now go and shoot yourself in the foot :)

```
  class ActionController::Base
    def render
      # Now I'm in charge of rendering!
    end
  end
```

Comment: I wonder if he's looking to override the view helper though, not through ActionController?

Answer (score 1):

It might help to know what kind of tweak you're trying to do. Modifying a core function like render is most likely not a good idea, and there's certainly a much easier way.

By overriding this, you'll affect every other place where render is used. Why not create your own render method as a helper?

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper
  def render_my_crazy_thing
    return "stuff you want to see: " + render(:partial => 'documents/form')
  end
end
```

The ActionView#render method handles all different cases of rendering, switching on different parameters: partials, collections of objects, etc. The `:partial => 'documents/form'` parameter is the ruby syntax for a hash (key => value).

Comment: "app/helpers" helpers are accessible in views only, not in controllers. Controller helps you usually put in app/controllers/application_controller.rb

Comment: Yes, but his example shows ERB... no sense clobbering the controller's render method too!